# How to return list of 'in', 'pre' and 'post' order of a binary search tree?

Tags: python-3.x, binary-search-tree

For my homework, I need to return a list containing the nodes with correct orders in binary tree according to the string(in, pre and post) that was given.  But it return `'None'` instead and I don't know what's wrong. Thanks for any kind of help.

```
class BinarySearchTree:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def create_new_bst(nums):
    root = None
    for num in nums:
        root = insert(root, num)
    return root
def insert (t, data):
    if not t:
        return BinarySearchTree(data)
    elif t.data == data:
        t.count += 1
    elif data < t.data:
        t.left = insert(t.left, data)
    else:
        t.right = insert(t.right, data)
    return t
def traverse(t, order):
    if order == 'in':
       return inorder(t)
    elif order == 'pre':
       return preorder(t)
    elif order == 'post':
       return postorder(t)

def inorder(root):
    lst = []
    if root: 
        inorder(root.left) 
        lst.append(root.data)
        inorder(root.right) 
    return lst
def postorder(root):
    lst = []
    if root: 
        postorder(root.left) 
        postorder(root.right) 
        lst.append(root.data)
    return lst
def preorder(root):
    lst = []
    if root: 
        lst.append(root.data)
        preorder(root.left) 
        preorder(root.right) 
    return lst

t = create_new_bst([55, 24, 8, 51, 25, 72, 78])
result = traverse(t, 'post')
print('Result =', result)
```

Comment: It is because the `traverse` method is not returning anything, hence when you try printing the result, it is `None`.

Comment: Further, on running your code it seems that the BST is not properly constructed. Nor are the traversals correctly generating the list. Please go through some tutorials and you should be able to figure things out.

Comment: Now I've fixed some problems but it just show '[55]', when it should be '[8, 25, 51, 24, 78, 72, 55]'. And now I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: That's exactly what I said. Even if you return a value from `traverse`, it would not work since you are not constructing the BST properly, or the list in the traversal. The `insert` method you are calling inside `create_new_bst` is not mentioned in your question. Moreover, `return t` is **inside** the `for` loop, so it only finishes one iteration. You need to go through everything and fix it.

Comment: Now I've changed and edited some things in 'create_new_bst' and 'traverse' but how can I fix the list?

Comment: Great. Your BST is now getting constructed properly. I'll answer with the changes needed to your traversals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apart from your initial problems with constructing the BST, the traversals were not updating the `lst` variable with the value returned from the `left` and `right` subtrees. The following code should work:

```
def inorder(root):
    lst = []
    if root:
        lst = inorder(root.left)
        lst.append(root.data)
        lst.extend(inorder(root.right))
    return lst

def postorder(root):
    lst = []
    if root:
        lst = postorder(root.left)
        lst.extend(postorder(root.right))
        lst.append(root.data)
    return lst

def preorder(root):
    lst = []
    if root:
        lst.append(root.data)
        lst.extend(preorder(root.left))
        lst.extend(preorder(root.right))
    return lst
```

`extend` is a list method that will add each item from the argument list to the end of the caller list.